# how to read String from List<Serializable>

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, xsd

I have an xsd schema

```
    <xs:complexType name="valueType" mixed="true">    
       <xs:sequence>    
          <xs:element name="filename" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />    
      </xs:sequence>    
   </xs:complexType>
```

and XML

```
    <datapoint>  
       <fieldname>somestring</fieldname>  
       <value>some string</value>  
    </datapoint>  
    <datapoint>  
       <fieldname>somestring</fieldname>  
       <value>some string</value>  
    </datapoint>  
    <datapoint>  
        <fieldname>somestring</fieldname>  
        <value>  
           </filedata>
           <filename>some string</filename>  
        </value>  
   </datapoint>
```

i used JAXB parser and genarated a class

```
          public static class Value {  
              @XmlElementRef(name = "string", type = JAXBElement.class)  
              @XmlMixed  
              protected List<Serializable> content;  

              public List<Serializable> getContent() {  
                if (content == null) {  
                   content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();  
                 }  
                 return this.content;  
              }  
            }
```

i am able to get the values using ValueObj.getContent() when

```
   <datapoint>  
        <fieldname>somestring</fieldname>  
        <value>some string</value>  
   </datapoint>
```

but i am getting an object for filename. how to read string from List when

```
       <datapoint>  
          <fieldname>somestring</fieldname>  
          <value> 

               <filename>some string</filename>  
           </value>  
        </datapoint>
```

do i have to use two xsd or one xsd? how can i get the values inside  tag as well as inside  tag.

Comment: I think it is impossible to help you. Serializable is AFIK a very common interface which allows you to create any xml based on the class which implemented that class. As long your array list conains such a generic data structure it will be impossible to write a sutable xsd file.

Comment: I also have same question,please help me if this got resolved

Comment: We need to have two xsd

Answer (score 1):

The `List<Serializable>` will contain `String`s for plain text parts and `JAXBElement<?>` objects for XML elements. You can use `JAXBElement.getName()` to check for the element's QName. In case you have complex types, you can get the corresponding java type (which is erased from JAXBElement due to Java type erasure) using `JAXBElement.getDeclaredType()`.